# Javascript "--- is Not Defined" Error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function "resizePortfolio" and I call it later by doing "resizePortfolio();" But the console says "Uncaught ReferenceError: resizePortfolio is not defined."  It's to make my slideshow responsive, but for some reason it's giving an error and I don't understand why...

I'd really appreciate you help.

```
function resizePortfolio() {
    slideshowTitleHeight = $('.slideshow_title').height() + 20;
    slideshowControlsHeight = $('.slideshow_controls').height() + 20;
    if (showFullScreen == true) {
        _w = $('#wrapper').width() - (slideshowPaddingLeft + slideshowPaddingRight); // width for the slideshow item
    } else {
        _w = $('#wrapper').width() - menuWidth - (slideshowPaddingLeft + slideshowPaddingRight); // width for the slideshow item
    }
    _h = $('#content').height() - (slideshowPaddingTop + slideshowPaddingBottom + slideshowControlsHeight + slideshowTitleHeight); // height for the slideshow item
    $('.slideshow, .slideshow li, .slideshow li, .slideshow li table, .slideshow li table td').css({'width':_w, 'height':_h});
    $('.slideshow li table td  img').css({'max-height':_h,'max-width':_w});

    $(slideshowContainer).children('li').each(function() {
        _imgH = $(this).find('img').height(); // height for the slideshow image
        _imgW = $(this).find('img').width(); // width for the slideshow image
        if ($(this).hasClass('assettype2')) {
            hasVideo = true;
        }
        // position for the share overlay
        if (hasVideo == true) {
            $(slideshowShareContainer, this).height(_h).width(_w);
            $(slideshowShareContainer, this).children('div').height(_h).width(_w);
            $('.slideshow_share_links', this).width(_w/2);
            var margin = _w/2;
            var marginTop = (_h/2) - (_h/2);
            $(slideshowShareContainer, this).css({'marginLeft': -margin});
        } else {
            $(slideshowShareContainer, this).height(_imgH).width(_imgW+1);
            $(slideshowShareContainer, this).children('div').height(_imgH).width(_imgW);
            $('.slideshow_share_links', this).width(_imgW/2);
            $('.slideshow_share_links.blog', this).width(_imgW);
            var margin = _imgW/2;
            var marginTop = (_h/2) - (_imgH/2);
            $(slideshowShareContainer, this).css({'marginLeft': -margin});
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: A stack trace of where the uncaught reference is found would help, may be it is not even anywhere in resizePortfolio()

Comment: I don't see keyboardNavigation anywhere in your code...

Comment: you should at least be getting a line number with that error.  what is it?

Comment: The console says "Uncaught ReferenceError: keyboardNavigation is not defined." in this '$(window).on('resize', function() {
 resizePortfolio();
});'

Comment: I doubt this code is causing the problem. It only calls jQuery functions, and there's no mention of `keyboardNavigation` anywhere in jQuery.

Comment: Sorry, the error is "Uncaught ReferenceError: resizePortfolio is not defined"

Comment: You're probably defining the function inside another function, but trying to reference it from outside that function.

Comment: @Barmar: I have jQuery(document).ready(function($){ on the very top of my js file. Could that be it?

Comment: It either means the file with your code isn't loaded or the function is [out of scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope).

Comment: If both the definition and call are inside that, then it's not a problem. But if the definition is inside that function, but the call to `on` is outside, then it's the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the call:

```
$(window).on("resize", resizePortfolio);
```

is inside the `$(document).ready(function() {...})` body, because the scope of the function name is just that function.