# *Functionname* not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

My console says that the function `weatherData` isn't defined (`Uncaught ReferenceError: weatherData is not defined`)

```
var days;
$("a").each(function(day){
    $(this).on("click", function(){weatherData(day);});
});

function weatherData(day){  
    weatherDay = this.theWeather.daily.data[day];
    show(weatherDay);
}
```

Comment: whether both the code are in a shared scope?

Comment: if there are in a shared scope... then it looks fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/XraTW/1/

Comment: My guess is this is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22443138/javascript-is-not-defined-error/22443397#22443397 but you haven't provided enough information to tell.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var days;
  $("a").each(function(day){
    $(this).on("click", function(){
     weatherData(day);
    });
  });
});

function weatherData(day){  
   weatherDay = this.theWeather.daily.data[day];
   show(weatherDay);
}
```

Comment: The error message on your code, which line is getting the error?

Comment: The line where weatherData(day); is.

Comment: What value does (day) contain? I think you need to expand more on what you wanting to do

Comment: An index of the clicked a-tag.

Comment: I think it will be helpful if you explain what you want the functionality to do

Comment: It don't have to start when the document load. Just when I click on an a-tag.
The day have to change when I click on that a-tag.

Answer (score 0):

I changed it to this and now it works!

```
weatherData = function(day){
    weatherDay = this.theWeather.daily.data[day];
    show(weatherDay);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>

<body>
<a href="" value='1' class='test'> 1 </a>
<a href="" value='2' class='test'> 2 </a>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
$('a').click(function(){
var number = $(this).text();
alert(number);
});
});


</script></body>
</html>
```

Obvious you have the jquery files and css at the top of the html documents